# Is there is way to autoload multiple file for one module in ruby?

Tags: ruby, autoload

I know that Kernel has a method autoload(module, filename) that can register a filename to be loaded the first time that module is accessed.

But if I have a module whose definition is split into multiple files, is there a way to autoload all the files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closer approach is to reference using `autoload` a file that represents the main definition for the module and add a require statement in that file to each additional file where the module is further redefined.

You should also ask yourself why you are splitting a definition into multiple files and if that's the best approach, if you are assuming that each file is equivalent relevant for the definition.

Answer (score 0):

You could have the autoloaded module file require (or better, require_relative) the other files. When doing this, a common approach is for this file to have only require statements and no code.